# How to replace (keyboard and TTS) languages in the App Inventor 2's Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, text-to-speech, hebrew, app-inventor

I want to test a button that will allow user to type in *Hebrew* and get TTS to say that text.

I don't have an android device, so am using the Emulator.

I defined the following:

[image: Set TTS language property]

and

[image: Set language in TTS]

But in the Emulator, Hebrew is not defined in either `home/menu/settings/language & keyboard/` or `home/menu/settings/text-to-speech/language`.

#### How can I replace some of the (useless for me) languages in the Emulator with other languages (both for keyboards and TTS)?

Comment: this thread  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/r6JL0jrlR-Q/Ho1-12XZMd0J might be interesting for you...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Taifun. I've already been to the URL you mentioned. Unfortunately, the post's writer assumes that YandexTranslator is already include in one's Palette (which is not true in my case) and I saw no mention as to how to get YandexTranslator to be added to App Inventor 2.

Comment: you can find the YandexTranslate component in the Media drawer, see also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/media.html#YandexTranslate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Taifun comments to my OP constitute the answer to the OP, and following his URLs, I tried to implement Hebrew speech in an ai2 script.

However, seems there's a particular problem with **Hebrew speech**, as nothing is heard for an Hebrew sentence (while the same configuration produced English speech without a problem, viz. [Can Hebrew be used with TextToSpeech and YandexTranslate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558102/can-hebrew-be-used-with-texttospeech-and-yandextranslate/27558135#27558135))