# Can Hebrew be used with TextToSpeech and YandexTranslate?

Tags: android-emulator, translation, text-to-speech, hebrew, app-inventor

When I try the following (i.e., spoken Hebrew) in App Inventor 2, I hear nothing:

[image: Hebrew configuration ("he", "il", "הכנס לרכבת") does not produce speech]

However, the following (switching parameters to spoken English) works just fine:

[image: English configuration ("en", "uk", "go into the train") succeeds in producing speech]

Note that I change the variables "language", "country", "setance", and "hebrew_sentance" to switch between spoken English (which succeeds) and spoken Hebrew (which fails).

**Is it possible to get ai2 to speak Hebrew?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MIT APP inventor support 65 languages and communicates 40 languages from text to speech. The problem is not in your programming within the app inventor, but Hebrew is not supported as a text to speech language, and is still in further development. I suggest that you should implement using Google APIs to solve for the inconvenience, because they support 180 languages and can communicate 105 languages for text to speech

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @dumbgamergirl: do you know of any URLs that explain how to use Google TTS APIs from App Inventor? (Alas, neither Google nor StackOverflow searches produced any meaningful results).

Answer (score 1):

don't want to disappoint you but google Text To Speech doesn't support Hebrew either.